# How to compute a Fourier series?

Tags: fourier-series, computational-mathematics, mathematica, python

Consider the Fourier series

$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}e^{-n^2\pi^2t}\cos( n\pi x).$$

How can it be written in python (or other programming languages) to compute $u(x,t)$ as a function of $x$ or $t$?

Comment: The series doesn't converge for $t>0$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector my bad, there was a typo in the $exp$.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to implement an infinite sum in a programming language? You could consider a finite sum upto some fixed $n$ as a reasonable approximation.

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid could you please suggest the implementation of a *finite sum with a reasonable approximation*?

Comment: The heat equation with funny initial values, I see. Do you want to investigate the smoothing of the initially rather "unsmooth" function with time?

Comment: @ProfessorVector For the sake of simplicity, I presented the simplified equation of a problem to figure out where to start. The original equation is $u(x,t)=50-\frac{400}{\pi^2}\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2p+1)^2}e^{-0.0001(2p+1)^2\pi^2t}\cos( (2p+1)\pi x)$

Comment: That's a triangle wave as initial values. It will get more cosinusoidal quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
In Python, you can discretize the function by defining $x_k = \frac{k}{N}\Delta x$, similarly you would discretize the $t$ variable in an interval $[0,T]$, then create a matrix with entries

$$A_{p, n}=\frac{1}{n^2}e^{-n^2\pi^2 t_p} \qquad n\in [0, N)$$

and use one of the functions in [Scipy's fast Fourier transform module](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.fft.html).